# variables {% set %} in a skeleton file's 'block' don't get recognized , and can't be used when extnding the file?

Tags: twig, symfony, symfony-3.1

I have a symfony3/twig skeleton template

```
page1/skeleton.twig
    {# set default values #}
    {% block content %}
    {% set test = {
            sec1: {
                title:   "null",
                content: 'null'
            },
      }
    %}
    {% endblock %}
    <ul>
19        {% for sec in test[0:] %}
        <li>
            <p>{{ sec.title }}</p>
            <div>
                <p>{{ sec.content }}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
     {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

I then create a layout template that extends the skeleton with 'real' data

```
page1/layout.html.twig
    {% extends 'page1/skeleton.html.twig' %}

    {% block content %}
    {% set test = {
        sec1: {
            title:   "title1",
            content: 'content2'
        },
        sec2: {
            title:   "title2",
            content: 'content2'
        }
    %}
    {% endblock %}
```

But when I generate/publish the page, Symfony fires an error

```
Variable "test" does not exist in :page1:skeleton.html.twig at line 19
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
```

complaining about the *skeleton* itself.

That 'test' array is defined in the skeleton. Afaict from reading the docs on 'block', 'extends' & 'set', and can't figure out what exactly the problem is.

What do I need to change to eliminate this error?

Comment: Do you still need help with this john_a?

Answer (score 2):

`blocks` in `twig` have their own variable scope.
Variables created inside a block can't be accessed outside of it.

Imo you should only test if the variable exist and otherwise create the default value :

<kbd>skeleton.twig</kbd>

```
    {% if not test  is defined %}
        {% 
            set test = {
                sec1: {
                    title:   "null",
                    content: 'null'
                },
            }
        %}
    {% endif %}
    <ul>
    {% for sec in test[0:] %}
        <li>
            <p{{ sec.title }}</p>
            <div>
                <p>{{ sec.content }}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

<kbd>controller.php</kbd>

```
<?php
    echo $twig->render('page/page.twig', array(
           'foo' => [
               'title' => 'title1',
               'content' => content1',
            ],
    );
```

Comment: > Variables created inside a block can't be accessed outside of it.

I'd read that blocks have access to outer scopes.  Which now I understand means exactly the opposite direction of what I was assuming. :-/

> Imo you should only test if the variable exist and otherwise create the default value

That works.  The 'addl' data can still be in .twig 'extends' -- just not in a 'block'.  IIUC, the twig compilation takes care of the order, processes the extend-ing template, and sets the var in-scope, overriding the parent's "if not defined" default.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Change this in the file page1/skeleton.twig:

```
{% for sec in test %}
```

Then it will work.
I tried it. Make sure you understand why!

Comment: @DarkBee wow, there is something like twigfiddle. Nice to know :D

Comment: Hi @DarkBee and @dragoste yes you are right. I was only trying to get the OP to do some **work**, not for **you** to do his work. So thus, thank you for the down votes! He already commented about his mistakes, about variables outside of the block which is a problem. But he hadn't admitted his other mistakes, for example on Line 20 the unclosed paragraph tag. The OP didn't even make an effort to try a`{{ dump( test ) }}` to see what that shows, and figure out from my answer what I was trying to get him to do.

Comment: Again, thanks for the down votes. I really appreciate it! By the way, you answer didn't even help the OP with what he is trying to do, which is extend the skeleton...

Comment: yes, DarkBee did.  Which is why I ack'd his answer, and said thanks.  As for doing work?  lol.  funny guy.  whine elsewhere about your down votes.  they're deserved.